# create user defined WHERE SQL phrase in r

Tags: sql, r

I am using `RODBC` to connect to a database. I would love for a user to be able to define wildcard strings to lookup in the SQL as part of a function. I cannot use CONTAINS as the database is not full-text indexed.

The SQL I want to create is

```
"SELECT *
FROM mydataTable
WHERE (ItemNM LIKE '%CT%' OR ItemNM LIKE '%MRI%' OR ItemNM LIKE '%US%')"
```

The user should be able to define as many wildcards as they like, all from the ItemNM field and all separated by OR.

```
myLookup<-function(userdefined){

  paste0("SELECT *
FROM mydataTable
WHERE ( LIKE '",userdefined,"')")


}
```

If I vectorise the userdefined (ie `userdefined<-c("US","MRI")`) then I end up with separate SQL strings which is no good. How can I get the output as above but for any length of user defined string where they are just defining the wildcard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :

```
myLookup <- function(userdefined) {
   paste0('SELECT * FROM mydataTable WHERE (', 
       paste0('ITENM LIKE %', userdefined, '%', collapse = " OR "), ')')
}

userdefined<-c("US","MRI")
myLookup(userdefined)
#[1] "SELECT * FROM mydataTable WHERE (ITENM LIKE %US% OR ITENM LIKE %MRI%)"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `glue`

```
library(glue)
mylookup <- function(userdefined){
   as.character(glue('SELECT * FROM mydataTable WHERE (', 
      glue_collapse(glue("ItemNM LIKE '%{userdefined}%'"), sep=" OR "), ')'))

  }

mylookup(userdefined)
#[1] "SELECT * FROM mydataTable WHERE (ItemNM LIKE '%US%' OR ItemNM LIKE '%MRI%')"
```